# Adding rows inside a loop

Tags: c#, closedxml

If I execute the following code fragment:

```
IXLRange dataRange = worksheet.Range(1, 1, myData.Count, 4);
foreach (var row in dataRange.Rows()) {
    //int cells = row.CellCount();
    if (isEndOfGroup) {
        row.InsertRowsBelow(1);
        var rowBelow = row.RowBelow();
        // Do stuff with the added row, like adding a subtotal
    }
}
```

What's actually happening here? It seems like the row collection being iterated on is being updated, which is what I want to happen, because the commented-out line throws an exception with the error "Range is invalid" on the next iteration, as if the row somehow hasn't been initialised yet.

I understand modifying a collection as you iterate through it is bad practice, but I've done this before without any issues.

What would be an alternative way of achieving this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using a `for` loop as Bagerfahrer suggested and having a second counter to keep track of the row number:

```
int rowNum = 1;  // Row numbering starts at 1
for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count; i++) {
    var row = worksheet.Row(rowNum);
    if (isEndOfGroup) {
        row.InsertRowsBelow(1);
        rowNum++;
        var rowBelow = row.RowBelow();
        // Do stuff with the added row, like adding a subtotal
    }
    rowNum++;
}
```

This allows me to index into `myData` for retrieving data and also keep track of where I'm writing to in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Never modify a collection while iterating... It is a bid.
Take advantage of the for loop.
When it did not raise an exception before, then you just changed the content of the row but not the reference of to row itself.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"Take advantage of the for loop"*?

Comment: The for loop don't use the `IEnumerable<Type>` that can not be changed while iterating (foreach loop gets the enumerator by `Rows().GetEnumerator()`. Instead the for loop can be used by entering your reference of your row in your list by index.